# How do I run phantomjs as a target of js-testrunner from within an intellij maven install?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, phantomjs

I have a strange situation on which I cannot get phantom tests to run from intellij.

```
java.io.IOException: The phantomjs executable cannot be launched from the path or from the value of the org.codehaus.jstestrunner.commandPattern property.See http://js-testrunner.codehaus.org/usage.html for instructions. Original exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phantomjs": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Now, I have no idea why this is because:

- I can access phantom from the command line, as 'mvn test' works, runs and passes the tests
- I have added it as a [path variable](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/path-variables.html)
- I have added it as a [path variable that is accessible by a GUI program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)
- I've check the permissions on the phantomjs file and they're as permissive as I can make them - they are permissive than the actual IntelliJ application, and 'owned' by the same owner / group
- I have restarted my Mac / IntelliJ numerous times.
- I have tried adding it as a 'VM' option for a 'mvn install' task:

  mvn test -Dorg.codehaus.jstestrunner.commandPattern="/usr/local/bin/phantomjs '%1$s' %2$s"

Can anyone think why the jstestrunner action that occurs as part of the mvn test target does not seem able to access / see my phantom installation

Comment: What is your Mac OS X version?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check: did you try to hardcode in your pom.xml the full path to the PhantomJS executable?

I know it's not the "final" solution, but it's to make sure it works if you pass it the full-qualified-path.

Comment: Also, it would be very useful if I can see the pom.xml, or part of it (the one where you invoke phantomjs).